# Get the commit id of merged Pull Requests

Tags: git

Over the development process, there are many commits to a code repository.
Some of them are merge commits, in other words, they carry the 'signal' to merge a particular Pull Request to master.

You can see the IDs of these commits easily using an online code repository, such as Github, Bitbucket etc...

However, can this be done locally?
Is there a way to get a list of the ids of the merge commits, and see which branch each one corresponds to ?

Comment: "merge commits, and _see which branch each one corresponds to_" Makes no sense. A branch is just a name temporarily applied to a single commit. Git has no concept of a stable branch. Merge commits have no "knowledge" of their parents as have been originally identified by some branch name. A merge commit does not "correspond" to any branch.

Comment: @matt Yeah you are right. However, mnestorov's answer helped me. It isn't 100% what i want, but i can identify the merge commit, thanks to its commit description.

Comment: Yes, very good point. If you wisely build historical info into the merge commit message you can read it later. That is what GitHub etc do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is

`git log --merges`

Additionally you can add the `--oneline` parameter to see a shorter version of your merges.

Comment: Thank you! There is no information on the branch (perhaps impossible, like matt said in a comment on my question). However, i can see the commit description and that helps a lot!